# Getting Local HTML5 Video working in Meteor generated iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, meteor, html5-video

I'm building an iOS app using Meteor that requires me to play locally stored mp4's but the mobile app is not displaying any videos.

I have this template:

```
    <template name="video">

{{#if cordova}}
    Mobile Player


    <video webkit-playsinline id="example_video_1" width="50%" height="20%">
        <source src="/my_vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video

 {{else}}
    Desktop

         <video control id="example_video_1" width="50%" height="20%" src="/my_vid.mp4">
        </video>

{{/if}}
</template>
```

The Desktop version works fine but I am experiencing issues getting the video to play in the iOS version.

This is my corresponding Video.js code:

```
if(Meteor.isClient)
{


Template.video.rendered = function()
{

    videojs("example_video_1",
      {
        "controls" : true,
        "autoplay": true,
        "techOrder" : ["html5", "flash"],
        preload: "auto"
      },
        function()
        {

        }
    )
}

Template.video.helpers({
    cordova: function()
    {
        getBlobURL("/my_vid.mp4", "video/mp4", function(url, blob) 
        {
            $("video")[0].src = url
        });


        return Meteor.isCordova;
    }
    })

function getBlobURL(url, mime, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("get", url);
  xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

  xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( this.response );
    var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: mime } );
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    callback(url, blob);
  });
  xhr.send();
}



}
```

This snippet:

```
function getBlobURL(url, mime, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("get", url);
  xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

  xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( this.response );
    var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: mime } );
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    callback(url, blob);
  });
  xhr.send();
}
```

Is a solution coming from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884264/uiwebview-local-video-audio-playback-in-ios-not-working-using-meteor-phonega). I tried to implement this solution but it is not resolving my issue.

I've also tried adding a config.xml and mobile-config.js file as described [here](http://blog.blairvanderhoof.com/post/78586868260/getting-the-html5-video-tag-to-work-in-cordova-for).

It seems the problem has to do with Cordova setting the wrong MIME-type and the SO question I referenced before had a solution that apparently worked but I can't seem to get it working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a Blob URL for your video is the correct route to take but you also have to be sure that your version of iOS is higher than 8.1.2 .

I upgraded to 8.2 and my code seemed to work fine afterwards.